# Why does text in Arial Black font specifically overlap text in the Run above it?

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, background

I have been experiencing a text formatting issue that only applies with text in Arial Black font. Using a TextBlock with two Runs, the bottom Run will overlap the top one if the text on it is Arial Black. The background of the second Run in particular is what is overlapping the Run above it. For any other font, no matter what size I set the text on the bottom Run, it won't overlap. The project I am experiencing this issue in is a WPF App using .NET Framework 4.8. I can add a snippet of code showing how I am setting the content of the TextBlock if need be.

[Screenshot using regular Arial font:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Buy.png)

[Screenshot using Arial Black font:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wke6o.png)

I have tried making the text overlap with numerous different fonts and none of them did it except Arial Black. I have tried making the overlap occur without the background of the Run being set and couldn't get it to happen, so the background size of Arial Black seems related to the problem. This issue has only been able to occur using Arial Black text and setting the background on the Run elements. It is as if the way the background size is determined for Arial Black is off.

Code to set content of TextBlock in MainWindow:

```
Run run = new Run("Size 16px______\r\n");
Run run2 = new Run("Size 48px");
//run.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial Black");
//run2.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial Black");
run.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
run2.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
run.FontSize = 16;
run2.FontSize = 48;
Color color = Colors.Red;
run.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
run2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
textBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
textBlock.Inlines.Add(run2);
```

For the MainWindow xaml, all that needs to be added is the TextBlock in the main grid:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"></TextBlock>
```

To switch between using Arial or Arial Black in the TextBlock, you can just comment or uncomment the run.FontFamily lines.

Comment: You need to provide your code if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer solving your problem, just showing how you can further investigate it. But since comments are too limited, I have to put my explanation in an answer :-(

There is a helpful tool for investigating such problems for WPF apps running in VS. It looks like this:

[image]

Or, when you click on it like this:

[image]

Click on *Select Element*
[image]

Click on your Textblock.

Click on *Go to Life Visual Tree*
[image]

This will show you your TextBlock within the visual tree and its parents:
[image]

Right click, then click on *Show Properties* and this will show you the values of actual size, etc. You also need to look at the properties of the parent to figure out why the TextBlock got its size.

Comment: I have already investigated the visual tree to get further details and nothing specific was found for the TextBlock that could help explain this disproportionate amount of space a Run with Arial Black takes up relative to other fonts. I will add code to the original post to recreate what I am seeing.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the Visual Tree does not provide any information how the Runs get placed within the TextBlock. If you use 2 TextBlocks, you can use the Visual Tree to investigate the layouting.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you use `Run` within `TextBlock` instead 2 TextBlocks ?

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Text="Size 16px______" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Background="Red"/>
  <TextBlock Text="Size 48px______" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="48" Background="Orange"/>
  <TextBlock Text="Size 16px______" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="16" Background="Yellow"/>
  <TextBlock Text="Size 48px______" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="48" Background="GreenYellow"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This works properly. You can use a `Grid` if you need a more complicated arrangement of the TextBlocks and you can create them in code behind.

To be honest, not many people use Runs, meaning maybe also not many understand the details how `TextBlock` layouts its content. I for example have no idea if what you discovered is a WPF bug or a "special feature" of `TextBlock` layouting.

Comment: The example I used to convey the issue was for the sake of reproducing it in the simplest scenario possible. The original problem was encountered with a RichTextBox and text was formatted with Run elements to put them on separate lines. I used a TextBlock to prove the problem was not an issue with the RichTextBox itself but was in fact an attribute of Arial Black directly related to the problem, so multiple TextBlocks is not going to solve my problem. I am looking for an explanation for why Arial Black behaves differently than other fonts, but I appreciate your response. Thanks for the help.

Comment: WPF is a great product but unfinished, Microsoft gave up on it for some time. Meaning you will find sometimes some strange behavior and you have to work around it. Arial Black seems to behave strangely and you might never find out why. Do you really need to use it ? If that is the case, you can actually put any Visual like TextBlock into InlineUIContainer. I know, it's a hack, but ...